# How can I SSH into Chrome OS?

Tags: ssh, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I can `ssh` from my Google Pixel Slate to any other computer. No problem.

I cannot `ssh` from any other computer into Chrome OS. I think it's because the shell is run as a VM and it even has its own set of IP address that's different than what Chrome OS is using.

So the question. Is there a way to SSH into Chrome OS? Some sort of NAT probably?

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/testing/autotest-developer-faq/ssh-test-keys-setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option for most people is to SSH into the Linux Beta Terminal (Crostini). With this, you can have access to a complete Linux VM running on your Chromebook, and you can install Linux apps through APT that run on your Chromebook's desktop.

SSH through Linux Beta is by far the easiest method and still allows you to SCP files to your Chromebook, open images, play audio files, and more functions.

**Detailed instructions with Photographs and Code can be found here...**

https://www.hackershark.com/2021/05/13/how-to-ssh-into-your-chromebook-through-linux-beta/

**Overview**

1. Remove the file at /etc/ssh/sshd_not_meant_to_be_run
2. Set the SSH Port in SSH config file to a custom port above 1024
3. Restart the SSH server for the new changes to take place
4. Foward the Custom port in Chromebook settings
5. SSH into your Chromebook

Comment: wayback link to instructions: https://web.archive.org/web/20210513172249/hackershark.com/2021/05/13/how-to-ssh-into-your-chromebook-through-linux-beta/

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned there are several options for accessing ChromeOS devices depending on what your goal is. The easiest is to enable SSH in Crostini and set up a port forward using the new options in the latest ChromeOS releases. The second easiest is Crouton which requires Developer mode, but can still maintain a lot of the system security features. The last, hardest, and least "secure" is  to configure the "host" ChromeOS run an SSH server, but this requires removing a lot of the security protections that make Chromebooks a really solid development platform.

There are probably a lot of posts covering SSH into Crostini or Crouton, so I'll just go over the "hard" option and will try to come back and update with a few links to the others as I come across consistently working and best practice posts for those.

HARD MODE aka YOLO:

If you want to SSH into the actual host operating system you need to enable the SSH service by switching into Developer Mode (wipes all data during the conversion). You can choose the option to enable "Debugging options" during the post reset set up, but I've found that this actually causes some issues later, so I'd recommend to just connect to the internet and log in like you normally would.

> NOTE: Switching to Developer Mode sets a firmware flag and even doing
> a Powerwash or Recovery from USB doesn't change the system from
> Developer Mode back to the normal mode. You have to press Space at the
> Developer mode warning or run a specific command from the Crosh shell
> after logging in to change the Developer Mode setting, and doing so
> triggers a wipe of all data for security purposes.

If you want to SSH into your ChromeOS host operating system you need to disable the rootfs read-only protection, note that this reduces the security of your system significantly, and making an incorrect change or deleting the wrong file (or a broken script or malware abusing your access) could cause ChromeOS to stop booting, forcing you to use a USB Recovery or perform a Powerwash which deletes all your user data.

After disabling the rootfs protection you can enable the SSH service by following the directions from the ChromeOS source.

There are 3 options, with the first being the Debugging that I recommend skipping, the second being the best IMO because you can disable password SSH and remove the "test keys" that aren't secure since they are publicly known, and the third requires running the sshd manually after each reboot, which probably isn't what you want if you need remote/unattended access to your Chromebook/Chromebox. Though for the 3rd option you may be able to avoid using the "test keys" as long as you can set the file permissions correctly for the `authorized_keys` file and store it under `/usr/local/` which ChromeOS doesn't touch during updates.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/overlays/chromiumos-overlay/+/master/chromeos-base/chromeos-sshd-init/files/openssh-server.conf.README#25

```
Copyright 2015 The Chromium OS Authors. All rights reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
found in the LICENSE file.

------------------------------
Instructions for enabling sshd
------------------------------
Normally base images will not automatically start sshd on boot. If sshd is
needed, below are a few recommended ways to start it, from simplest to most
complicated.
1. OOBE debugging features.
  This is the easiest way to enable sshd, but if OOBE has already been bypassed
  the machine will have to be powerwashed first to get back to OOBE.
  Enabling the OOBE debugging features will cause sshd to start automatically
  on each boot, and both password and test key access will be enabled.
  For more information on OOBE debugging features, see
  dev.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/debugging-features.
2. Run a helper program.
  An executable named dev_features_ssh is available to enable sshd. Rootfs
  verification must be removed first or the helper program will have no effect.
  This will cause sshd to start automatically on each boot with test key
  access. Password access can optionally be enabled after rootfs verification
  has been removed.
  # Remove rootfs verification.
  $ /usr/share/vboot/bin/make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification
  $ reboot
  # Install sshd startup files.
  $ /usr/libexec/debugd/helpers/dev_features_ssh
  # Allow password access (optional).
  $ passwd
3. Manually start sshd.
  This is the least convenient option, but doesn't require OOBE or rootfs
  verification removal, so can be used without changing the system too much.
  Unlike the above methods, this will not auto-start sshd on boot.
  Additionally, password access is not possible without rootfs verification
  removal, so test keys must be used to SSH into the device.
  # Create host keys (only needs to be done once).
  $ mkdir -p /mnt/stateful_partition/etc/ssh
  $ ssh-keygen -f /mnt/stateful_partition/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa
  $ ssh-keygen -f /mnt/stateful_partition/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -N '' -t ed25519
  # Open firewall and start sshd (must be done on every boot).
  $ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
  $ /usr/sbin/sshd \
    -oAuthorizedKeysFile=/usr/share/chromeos-ssh-config/keys/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 2):

There have been some changes to the Linux container. It can now [forward](https://chromeos.dev/en/web-environment/port-forwarding) ports, but only to non-privileged port numbers (1024 and above).

There is already an SSH daemon running on port 2222. This does something for ChromeOS to start the container and is an SFTP-only server.

What you can do is install your own SSH daemon and run it on a different port, (I use 2223) and use the port-forwarding feature in the host OS, given above.

It is an inconvenience but the port-forwarding is not restored when you stop and then start the container. You have to manually start forwarding in the Linux settings tab after you have stopped the container.

If you do get it working, remember to backup your Linux container. The Linux containers can break and not startup from the Terminal application.

If the container is not started from the Terminal application, it is not possible to start port-forwarding. (There is a way to manually start a container with CROSH and then use termina and then lxc. You can use this if the Terminal no longer starts the container and you want to get onto it.)

Comment: And you activate the new installation of sshd using a SystemD service and that has  a Condition that prevents startup. So you should edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config to change the port number, start the service, check the status of the service, it should explain the Condition and you then delete a file.

Comment: You should also add a password to your user account in the container and then you can use ssh-copy-id as usual, but add the port you use.